# set matplotlib backend on jupyter for plots that change over the time

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I would like to draw my plots out of the Jupyter notebook page. As I remember "%matplotlib qt" should be the right command to type at the beginning of the script

```
%matplotlib qt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.01)
y = np.sin(np.pi*x)/(np.pi*x)
plt.figure() 
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

But it doesn't work as I get an inline plot and the following warning

```
Warning: Cannot change to a different GUI toolkit: qt. Using notebook instead.
```

Could you help me understanding what's wrong with my jupyter?

The reason for which I would like to plot outside the browser is that it looks the only way to have a plot that changes over the time on Jupyter, in fact I can easily do this job on spyder with the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.01)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
for j in range(1, 10):
    y = np.sin(np.pi*x*j)/(np.pi*x*j)
    line, = ax.plot(x, y, 'b')
    plt.pause(0.3)
    plt.draw()
    line.remove()
```

But at this stage this code doesn't properly work on Jupyter. Is there any alternative and interesting way to provide plots that change over the time on Jupyter?

Answer (score 0):

This code at least get you an external window in which to do stuff.
Taken from pythonspot.com. I'm sure there'll be a way to add movement etc. but I'm 8 hours past my bedtime zzzzz

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMenu, QVBoxLayout, QSizePolicy, QMessageBox, QWidget, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

import random

class App(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.title = 'PyQt5 matplotlib example - pythonspot.com'
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 400
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        m = PlotCanvas(self, width=5, height=4)
        m.move(0,0)
        self.show()


class PlotCanvas(FigureCanvas):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)
        self.plot()


    def plot(self):

        x = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.01)
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        ax.set_title('PyQt Matplotlib Example')
        for j in range(1, 10):
            y = np.sin(np.pi*x*j)/(np.pi*x*j)
            line, = ax.plot(x, y, 'b')
            self.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```